# How to access the icon of a feature retrieved from text in a vector-layer?

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, clustering

I`m using OpenLayers to show POIs on a map. These POIs are loaded from a textfile and I`m using a Vector Layer to get it onto the map - works great. 
Now I want to use the cluster strategy to have points clustered to one when the user is zooming out and the points get to close (see this great [tutorial](http://bit.ly/39VmEa)). Works, too.  But only for a static image. I want to get the image that is defined in the textfile, but I`m not able to get this.
The text file is in the normal format for OpenLayers.Format.Text. The image is defined in the column named icon and as I told, it is shown when not using clustering.
According to the Source code of OpenLayers.Format.Text.js the value of the column icon should be stored in the externalGraphic-property. But this doesn`t seem to be the case. Here`s my code to try to get the Image:

```
var clusterStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
    externalGraphic: "${icon}",
    graphicWidth: 24,
graphicHeight: 24,
    description: "${description}"
}, {
    context: {
        icon: function (feature) {
    if(feature.cluster)
    {
        feature.externalGraphic="/img/clusterimage.png";
    }
    return feature.externalGraphic;
        }...
```

I`ve also tried other constructs like

```
feature.cluster[0].attributes['icon']
```

or

```
feature.externalGraphic=feature.cluster[0].attributes['icon']
```

to get the icon, but neither worked.
So where is the icon stored, how to access it? Is there a qay to iterate the attributes-object? 
I`m using OpenLayers 2.12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found the solution myself - it was not a mistake in the code lines I`ve posted. The problem were silly parameters passed to the strategy-constructor: I used the following code to create the cluster strategy:

```
var clusterStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster({ distance: 15, threshold: 1 });
```

The problem was to set the threshold to 1. That erased (or overlapped, whatever) the icon. So I`ve set the threshold to 2 and then it worked as described in the amazing tutorial from the openflight-project that I`ve posted in the question.

Comment: works for KML layers as well.  U ROK!